# Can't do multiple groups in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to show a statistics count, per month, per manufacturer from a MongoDB collection using Linq.I would like to see my data as:

```
[{
     Manufacturer: '',
     Statistics: [{
          Month: '',
          Counts: 0
     }]
}]
```

So I am trying the following linq query:

```
var result = _statisticsRepository
            .All()
            .GroupBy(g => g.ManufacturerId)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Manufacturer = s.Key,
                Statistics = s
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Values["DATA_MONTH"])
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        Month = a.Key,
                        Counts = a.Sum(d => d.Count)
                    })
            });
```

When I try this code I get this error:

```
NotSupportedException: The method GroupBy is not supported in the expression tree: {document}.GroupBy(a => a.Values.get_Item("DATA_MONTH")).
```

Am I doing this the wrong way or is this a limitation I have in the C# driver? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) framework instead LINQ to get the data that you need:

```
var group1 = new BsonDocument
                  {
                      { "_id", new BsonDocument{{"ManufacturerId", "$ManufacturerId"},{"DATA_MONTH", "$DATA_MONTH"} }},
                      { "Count",  new BsonDocument 
                                             { 
                                                 { 
                                                 "$sum", $Count } 
                                             }   }
                  };

var group2 = new BsonDocument
                  {
                      { "_id", "$_id.ManufacturerId" },
                      { "Statistics ", new BsonDocument { { "$addToSet",new BsonDocument{{"Month", "$_id.DATA_MONTH"},{"Count","$Count"} } } }}, 
                  };

var result = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Manufacturers").Aggregate()
                                                                  .Group(group1)
                                                                  .Group(group2)
                                                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: anybody knows how u implement pipelinedefination with 2.0 driver?

Comment: @SufyanJamil, that solution was tested using 2.0 driver if my mind doesn't fail me

Comment: sorry i did not explain my issue. I have a dynamic set of aggregate query thats y i have to create custom pipeline on the basis of query. I cant use extension method as i dont know what will be inside my query..